# Rebuild redis docker with Dev Containers failling cause port is already allocated

Tags: docker, docker-compose, vscode-extensions, vscode-devcontainer, devcontainer

I'm trying to work with VSCode Dev Containers, but I facing an issue.

I have a docker-compose.yml, with 2 services:

```
version: '3'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  worker:
    depends_on:
      - redis
    image: app
    build: .
   ...
```

But if I try to run `Dev Containers: Rebuild and Reopen`, it fails to bring up the new redis container because the port 6379 is already in use: `0.0.0:6379 failed: port is already allocated`

Then, to avoid this I manually run `docker stop <container_id>`. But I want to automate this , or put some command inside my docker-compose.yml to prevent this, is it possible?

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're encountering the 'port is already in use' error because a port on your system can only be used by one process at a time, and Docker containers run in isolated environments, each with its own set of ports. To resolve this issue, you have a few options:

1. **Change Port Mapping**: In your Docker Compose file (`docker-compose.yml`), you can modify the port mapping to use a different port on your host machine. For example, you can change the mapping from `6379:6379` to `8080:6379`. This allows you to access the containerized service on port 8080 of your host machine.
2. **Use `docker run` with Port Binding**: When starting a container using `docker run`, you can specify port binding using the `-p` or `--publish` option. For example: `docker run -p 8080:6379 my_redis_container`. This maps port 6379 in the container to port 8080 on your host.
3. **Use a Reverse Proxy**: If you have multiple services that need to use the same port, consider using a reverse proxy like Nginx or Traefik. It can route requests to the appropriate containers based on hostname or path, allowing you to avoid port conflicts.
4. **Stop Existing Containers**: You can manually stop the container that's using the conflicting port by running `docker stop <container_id>`. To automate this, you can create a script that stops the container before starting your development containers.

If you have any more questions or encounter any further issues, please feel free to ask. I'm here to help!